# An example on disconnected subset

Tags: general-topology

Find a topological space X and a disconnected subset A of X such that for any two non-empty open sets U and V  partitioning X, we have either "A is contained in U" or "A is contained in V".

I have given it a decent amount of thought but the answer is still a far cry.

Comment: Which definition of "disconnected" are you using?

Comment: @GregMartin Sorry, I misread.

Comment: As stated right now, the problem admits a trivial solution: any space $X$ that is connected but has a disconnected subset.

Comment: If $A$ is disconnected, then you can find a partition of $A$. This means that the partition of $A$ cannot be extended to a partition of $X$, i.e. $X$ must be connected, or at elast $A$ is contained in a connected component of $X$.

Comment: @Crostul...but it's clear from the question that X is disconnected and that U,V form one of the disconnections

Comment: @krishna2016 Where is it stated then that $X$ is disconnected? "For any two non-empty sets..." does not imply that such sets exists. From there the comment of Greg.

Comment: @drhab....The partitioning of X into two disjoint nonempty open sets makes it disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from Munkres's Topology, and I made it more concrete.
Since U and V are both open in X, the sets $A \cap U$ and $A \cap V$ are open in $A$.(I thought this is the breaking point, since the definition of subspace is not easy to handle.)These two sets are disjoint(Use premises in the problem and sets formulas) and their union is A(Use formulas in sets); if they were both nonempty, they would constitute a separation of A. Therefore, one of them is empty. Hence A must lie entirely in U or in V.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ...I forgot to use $... and I have fixed them.

Comment: why does one of them need to be empty?, it is given that A is disconnected, not connected!!